# Copy and Paste a Column only if data is present above it (Such as a name) in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have been using StackOverflow for a while now and just love this community. I know I can get an answer for any problem hopefully.

Ok so here is my issue, I have been performing a "Frankenstein" of a script from several posts on this site. I want to copy and paste a column of an Array Formula beneath specific headers until there are no more headers. For example, in the row F5 through W5, if there is a name, I want to copy the range that has an array formula beneath it, say in the range F156:F323, and paste that formula in the name under the G Column, H Column, so on until there are no more names between that range...

Below is my attempt to solve it but I keep getting errors

```
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Formula As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Main")
lastCol = ws.Range("F" & Columns.Count).End(xlRight).Column
Set Formula = Sheets("Main").Range("F156:F323")

With ws
    For i = 6 To lastCol
    If len(trim.range("F" & i).Value)) <> 0 then _
    .Range(i & 156).formulaarray = 'my formula here'
Next i
End With
```

Post any questions you may have and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are flipping columns and rows in many instances.

Use the Range Object `Cells` instead of `Range`.  It allows using column references in numbers instead of letters.

Assign the formula directly.

```
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Frmla As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Main")
lastCol = ws.Cells(5, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set Frmla = ws.Range("F156:F323")

With ws
    For i = 6 To lastCol
    If Len(Trim(.Cells(5, i).Value)) <> 0 Then
        .Range(.Cells(156, i), .Cells(323, i)).FormulaR1C1 = Frmla.FormulaR1C1
    End If
Next i
End With
```

Comment: Gah. Beat me to it XD

Comment: ahhhhh, let me give that a shot, thanks Scott Craner!

Comment: lastCol = ws.Range(5, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Comment: The error message reads: Run_time Error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed

Comment: That is not what I have in the code.  I have `lastCol = ws.Cells(5, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`  I have Cells, not Range.

Comment: Ok great, sorry about that, works now! Thanks Scott! One more question for you, the formula that I used to copy from has absolute reference cells that are used in collaboration with the cells of each respective column that I copying to, how can I make that happen instead of it just only copying the formula from the initial column?

Comment: Alright Scott, you are the man! One more issue I see, the first column of all of the copied columns is solid, works great, but in the second column, the formula changes from =($E$5:$E$154,F5:F154,,2) to =($E$5:$E$154,F6:F155,,2)...so essentially the second,third, fourth, etc. is dropping down a row each time rather than keeping the same range as the first row of the column.

Comment: Change your formulas in column F to be absolute where you want them to be absolute.  Highlight the references in the formula then hit the F4 till the right combination of Absolute and Relative references are correct. @Eddie

Comment: @ScottCraner ok so if I wanted the formula to be                                       =($E$5:$E$154,F5:F154,,2) for the first column,                                          =($E$5:$E$154,G6:G154,,2) for the second column and so on, how would I amend the script to do so?

Comment: @Eddie  `=($E$5:$E$154,F$5:F$154,,2)`

Comment: @ScottCraner but will the "F$5:F$154" part of the formula change for each new column to "G$5:G$154" for the second column?

Comment: @ScottCraner I got it to work Scott, thank you for your patience with me!